# how to resize the jquery button (through CSS)

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui

Hi Folks i'm new to JQuery

i want re size JQuery button 
my code is

```
<input type="submit" id="Btn1" value="Login"/>
```

in script

```
 $(document).ready(function(){
           $("#Btn1").button();
   });
```

But i get large font and big button, i want that in small size through CSS.

Thanks in Advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Jquery UI uses relative EM's to size all of their elements. Without some cursory CSS to set the font-size globally in a Jquery UI project you will end up with massive buttons and large text across the majority of the UI's widgets.

To fix this across all Jquery UI elements set the font-size absolutely on the body.

```
body {
    font-size:10pt; // or 12px
}
```

This will screw with all other font sizing you have on your site so use with caution when retro-coding something like this into your CSS.

Alternatively, you can isolate the highest level parent and declare an absolute font-size that is inherited by the buttons and then sized relatively by Jquery UI.

```
.button_container {
    font-size:10pt; // or 12px
}
```

Comment: also i want change the Background color

Comment: To maintain the Jquery-UI look and feel, I'd suggest going back through the themeroller, build it how you'd like it to look. And then extract the `ui-state-default`, `ui-state-highlight`, `ui-state-selected` background styles and then apply them directly to the button element.

Answer (score 0):

css code:

```
#Btn1 {
  font-size: small;
}
```

or:

```
#Btn2 {
  font-size: 50%;
}
```

[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/vKmkJ/)

Answer (score 0):

To re-size the button do this:

```
.button_class_name {
 display: block;
 width: 60%;
```

}

Answer (score 0):

Jquery ui has it's own stylesheets to render as Button, it uses different classes behind the scenes to achieve the functionality. you can check the demos [`Jquery Button`](http://api.jqueryui.com/button/)

jquery uses `ui-button` class to decorate the button, you can override the settings like this

```
input.ui-button
{
    font-size:14px;
    padding:.3em 1em;
}
```

and a [`Working Demo`](http://jsfiddle.net/xRfwJ/)

​